# hover in css have does no effect when element is hoverd

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I made a bunch of divs stacked on each other, and I want each div to change its background color whenever its hover, but that's not what happens

When I hover an item its background color should change to green,
but it doesn't work even that I wrote `div.oldiv:hover{background-color: #48FF0D;}`

The problem is probably in CSS code.

Here is a snippet :

```css
body{
  background-color: #48FF0D;
}
#bigdiv {
  height: 90%;
  width: 100%;
}
.oldiv {
  height: 0.390625%;
  width: 100%;}
div.oldiv:hover{
  background-color: #48FF0D;
}
#bigdiv2 {
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.btn {
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 28px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.uptodown {
  background-color: #e7e7e7;
  color: black;
}
.uptodown:hover {
  background: #ddd;
}
.l{
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <script>
  var b = "",k = "",a,q,d;
for(a = 0;a<=256;a++){
  d ="    <div id=\"du\" class=\"oldiv\" style=\"background-color: rgb("+a+","+a+","+a+");\"></div>";
  q ="    <div id=\"du\" class=\"oldiv\" style=\"background-color:rgb("+(256-a)+","+(256-a)+","+(256-a)+");\"></div>";
  b = b+"\n"+d;
  k = k+"\n"+q;
}

window.onload = function (){
  document.getElementById("bigdiv").innerHTML = b;
  document.getElementById("bigdiv2").innerHTML = k;
}
function utd(a){
  var bigdiv = document.getElementById("bigdiv");
  var bigdiv2 = document.getElementById("bigdiv2");
  if(a == 0){
    bigdiv.style.height = "0";
    bigdiv2.style.height= "90%";
  }else{
    bigdiv.style.height = "90%";
    bigdiv2.style.height= "0";
  }
}
  </script>
  <div id="bigdiv">
  </div>
  <div id="bigdiv2">
  </div>
  <div>
    <button class="btn uptodown" onclick="utd(0)">white to black</button>
    <button class="btn uptodown l" onclick="utd(1)">black to white</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Don't word about all the Javascript, its just to generate elements and adding them to HTML

Comment: "when I put the mouse over the item nothing gets" what does this mean?  Please describe what it *is doing* and what you *want it to do*.

Comment: I want when i hover the mouse up the div "class oldiv" his color change to the green

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what the purpose of this code is, but I think I have fixed it..... Whatever it is :P

Your `#bigdiv` and `#bigdiv2` percentage height were not working because the height of the document wasn't 100%. So I just added `html, body {height:100%;}` to fix that.

```css
/* code added START */
html, body {
  height:100%;
}
div.oldiv:hover {
  background-color: #48FF0D!important;
}
/* code added END */
body{
  background-color: #48FF0D;
}
#bigdiv {
  height: 90%;
  width: 100%;
}
.oldiv {
  height: 0.390625%;
  width: 100%;
}
/* div.oldiv:hover{background-color: #48FF0D;} */
#bigdiv2 {
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.btn {
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 28px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.uptodown {
  background-color: #e7e7e7; 
  color: black;
}
.uptodown:hover {
  background: #ddd;
}
.l {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script>
var b = "",k = "",a,q,d;
for(a = 0;a<=256;a++){
  d ="    <div id=\"du\" class=\"oldiv\" style=\"background-color: rgb("+a+","+a+","+a+");\"></div>";
  q ="    <div id=\"du\" class=\"oldiv\" style=\"background-color:rgb("+(256-a)+","+(256-a)+","+(256-a)+");\"></div>";
  b = b+"\n"+d;
  k = k+"\n"+q;
}
function utd(a) {
  var bigdiv = document.getElementById("bigdiv");
  var bigdiv2 = document.getElementById("bigdiv2");
  if(a == 0) {
    bigdiv.style.height = "0";
    bigdiv2.style.height= "90%";
  } else {
    bigdiv.style.height = "90%";
    bigdiv2.style.height= "0";
  }
}
</script>

<div id="bigdiv">
  <script>document.write(b);</script>
</div>
<div id="bigdiv2">
  <script>document.write(k);</script>
</div>
<div>
  <button class="btn uptodown" onclick="utd(0)">white to black</button>
  <button class="btn uptodown l" onclick="utd(1)">black to white</button>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for the comment but i want to change the background-color not for the big div just for the small div (class oldiv)

Comment: The background colour of the `oldiv` was changing. They were just all changing at the same time. I am guessing you want the `oldiv` backgrounds to change individually, so I have update my code snippet to reflect that.

Answer (score -1):

Well, there is no use of Javascript here. I'm not able to understand what problem you're facing but refer here : https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp

CSS already has property of `hover` and can be used like `element:hover {your properties inside like whatever event has to be happened on hover}`. There is no need to use JS here. Hope this helps.

UPDATE:

I would also suggest you to follow good practice of writing JS code and CSS code in a separate file not in a HTML file.

Comment: firstly Thank you for the comment
Secondly i use js here because if i do not use them you should type a very long code